# Strange Ruby error on console

Tags: ruby

I keep getting this error whenever I do anything related to Ruby whether its the Rails console or running a gem. What could be the cause and how can I fix this?

warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local
```

This error message comes up because your `/usr/local` is world-writeable, which is a Bad Thing---it enables other users to place trojan horses on your system.